What is the expected maximum location reached in a $1$ dimensional random walk?
Consider a random walk in $1$ dimension starting at the location $x=0$. In each time step, the walker moves left $1$ position with probability $(1-p)$ and right $1$ position with probability $p$. Given $N$ steps, we may see what the furthest right location the random walker reaches. What is the expected value of this location?
So far, I was able to solve the case with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ by finding a closed form solution. The number of paths the walked has reaching a maximum position of $N-d$ is ${N}\choose{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}}\rfloor} $. This yields a probability of reaching $N-d$ of $2^{-N}*$ ${N}\choose{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}}\rfloor} $. Summing these over all $d$ gives the expectation.
To show this, I found a recurrence relation. A similar recurrence relation occurs for the asymmetric case. If we let $M(N,d)$ be the event that a maximum of $N-d$ is reached after $N$ steps, then we have the following relation for $0\leq d <N$:
$\mathbb{P}(M(N,d)) = (1-p)*\mathbb{P}(M(N-1,d-1)) + p*\mathbb{P}(M(N-1,d+1)$
We also require for $d=N$ That $\mathbb{P}(M(N,N)) = \sum_{d=0}^{N-1}{\mathbb{P}(M(N,d))}$
I am unsure how to solve this recurrence relation for general $p$.

The law of the iterated logarithm treats the $p=\frac12$ case (though classically looking for fluctuations of either sign); I suspect it also applies to the general $p$ case once the expectation is subtracted off, although perhaps the leading constant depends on $p$.

The problem can be solved by relating the maximum (highest) position
of a random walk to its first passage times.
Consider a discrete random walk starting at $x=0$,
each step being $+1$ or $-1$ with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$,
respectively.
Denote as ${\bf T}_m$ the first passage time
of this random walk through the level $m \geq 0$,
and as ${\bf M}_N$ the maximum position attained
during its first $N$ steps; clearly $0 \leq {\bf M}_N \leq N$.
The fundamental relation is
$P({\bf M}_N < m) = P({\bf T}_m > N)$, in words:
the maximum position ${\bf M}_N$ in $[0,N]$ will be smaller than $m$
if and only if the first passage to the level $m$ occurs
only after step number $N$, that is, if ${\bf T}_m > N$.
Naturally, the same relation holds for $m+1$, namely,  $P({\bf M}_N < m+1) = P({\bf T}_{m+1} > N)$, and subtracting the first
from the second of these equations we get the probability mass function
(pmf) $f_N$ of ${\bf M}_N$
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f_N(m) & = & P({\bf M}_N = m) \; = \; P({\bf T}_{m+1} > N) - P({\bf T}_{m} > N)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, the pmf, say, $g(x|m)$ of the first passage time ${\bf T}_{m}$
through the fixed level $m$ is well-known to be (cf., Feller, vol. I, ch. XIV.5)
\begin{eqnarray*} 
g(x|m) \; = \; P({\bf T}_m = x) & = & \frac{m}{x} \, {x \choose \frac{x-m}{2} } \, 
p^{\frac{x+m}{2}} \, (1-p)^{\frac{x-m}{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
when $x \geq m$ and $x$ and $m$ have the same parity, and $g(x|m)=0$ else;
$g(0|0)$ is interpreted as $1$.
Clearly, then, $P({\bf T}_{m} > N) = 1-\sum_{x=m}^N \, g(x|m)$, and so  the pmf $f_N$ of the maximum position ${\bf M}_N$ is
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f_N(m) & = &  \sum_{x=m}^N \, g(x|m) - \sum_{x=m+1}^N \, g(x|m+1) 
\end{eqnarray*}
The expected value of the maximum position ${\bf M}_N$ attained during
the first $N$ steps then is $E[{\bf M}_N] = \sum_{m=1}^N \, m f_N(m)$.
For example, for $p=0.55$ the expected maximum position attained
during the first $N=36$ steps equals $6.397$.
Naturally, for $p \geq \frac{1}{2}$ the expected maximum position
increases with $N$ unboundedly.
For $p<\frac{1}{2}$ the random walk drifts towards negative values,
and for large $N$ the pmf of the maximum position then tends to
$P({\bf M}_N=m) = \lambda^m (1-\lambda)$ for $m=0,1, \ldots$,
where $\lambda=\frac{p}{1-p}$. In particular, for large $N$ the expected maximum then tends to the finite limit $\frac{p}{1-2p}$, and the probability $f_N(0)$ that the random walk will never enter the positive half-field tends to $\frac{1-2p}{1-p}$.
The Figure below shows the expected maximum position (ordinate) as a function of $N$ (abscissa) for $p=0.45$ (bottom), $p=0.50$ (middle), and $p=0.55$ (top).

